# java.net.ConnectException : Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:1731 using ChromeDriver Chrome through Selenium Java in Spring Bot

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

I have selenium based web application developed using spring boot. The server is located as VM Instance of google cloud server.

Please find below the details about the versions.

Spring Boot - 2.0.0.RELEASE

Selenium - 3.9.1

Linux - Debian 4.9.130-2 (2018-10-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux

Chrome Driver - 2.35.528139 (47ead77cb35ad2a9a83248b292151462a66cd881)

Google Chrome - 70.0.3538.110

JDK - 1.8.0_232

From the past few days, I am facing a strange issue, application works fine when business hours start but after few hours it becomes unstable and whole application stop working, even user can not login.
After digging more for this issue I found the below error from server logs. I have to restart the VM Instance in order to fix it.

[image]
.

After restart, it works fine for a few hours and then we face same issue again.

Also, I have noticed that while sending an email we face the below issue which works fine before 
a few minutes.
[image]

I also verified the server resource usage but didn't find any suspicious activity.
I googled for this issue but most of the solutions are provided for the problem being faced while running it first time. However, in my case it works fine for few hours and then start having this issue.

Please help me to understand the issue and root cause of this problem. It would be better if you can suggest a solution as well.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its been my experience that when an app stops working after a period of time that there is either a resource leak or an app crash.  When you get the error that you can no longer connect to an app at port 1731, see if anything is still listening on that port.  At a fresh boot, see what is listening at that port.  Check that you aren't running out of memory or you aren't leaking open file descriptors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This error message...

```
java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:1731
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was unable to initiate/spawn a new *Browsing Context* i.e. *Chrome Browser* session.

Your main issue is the **incompatibility** between the version of the binaries you are using as follows:

- You are using *chromedriver=2.35*
- Release Notes of [*chromedriver=2.41*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.35/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v62-64**

- Presumably you are using *chrome=70.0*
- Release Notes of [*ChromeDriver v2.44*](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.44/notes.txt) clearly mentions the following :

> Supports **Chrome v69-71**

- Your *Selenium Client* version is *3.9.1* which is almost **2** years older.

So there is a clear mismatch between *Selenium Client v3.9.1* , *ChromeDriver v2.35* and the *Chrome Browser v70.0*

---

### Solution

Ensure that:

- *Selenium* is upgraded to  current levels [Version 3.141.59](https://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/).
- *ChromeDriver* is updated to  current [ChromeDriver v79.0.3945.36](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=79.0.3945.36/) level.
- *Chrome* is updated to  current *Chrome Version 79.0* level. (as per [ChromeDriver v79.0 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/79.0.3945.36/notes.txt))
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- If your base *Web Client* version is too old, then uninstall it through [*Revo Uninstaller*](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo_uninstaller_free_download.html) and install a recent GA and released version of *Web Client*.
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was bcoz of chrome driver instance was closed in the middle of test execution. so it was not able to get that particular chrome driver to process the selenium commands. I had to tweak the logic of chrome instantiation and closure as in my case, parallel 3 chrome instances were opened and these were getting closed in the middle of execution so the problem was not finding a particular needed chrome driver instance.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).